# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' when using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: xmlhttprequest

Following this documentation of Codeship API: https://apidocs.codeship.com/v2/projects/update-project

I am trying to use `XMLHttpRequest` to fetch the data. The code is generated from the documentation, so I am assuming it should work.

```
var data = "{}";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;


xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("GET", "https://api.codeship.com/v2/organizations/uuidhere/projects?type=basic");
console.log('good');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
console.log('ok');
xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", token here);

xhr.send(data);

console.log(data)
```

However, when I test it in my localhost, it gives me

`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.`

It's weird that it still happens after putting

`xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');`

Please help

Comment: [The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header wants to be set by the `API`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) It is — not — possible with `AJAX`. Use a `backend` service like `cURL`.

Comment: @AjAX. How can I use that in `JavaScript` though?

Comment: You cannot. Look for `Same-Origin-Policy` of a browser.

Comment: @AjAX. What do you mean? If I cannot use it, how come there is an API for it?

Comment: You want to use your `server`. Like `PHP` and `cURL`. That is intended.

Comment: @AjAX. I tried the command with curl and it worked. What do I have to do to use this in a server?

Comment: [We plan to add Ruby and Javascript API clients in the near future.](https://apidocs.codeship.com/v2/introduction/api-clients#ruby-javascript) All written.

Comment: @AjAX. So if I am building a React website right now, how should I use the server to fetch this API?

Comment: You want to `ajax` into your server. And then go from there with `cURL`.

Comment: Do I need like an external database that stores the API data?

Comment: To avoid server downs of them only. You can do that in a file also. With `JSON`.